# The stamps (pictures) overlap in the PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, stamp

I wrote the following code to stamp a PDF.

imagefile = stamps to be added

filename = PDF's file path

My problem is that the stamps added to each page are overlapping. I want to bring these stamps together. How can I do it? Thanks.

```
 private void damga(string resimdosyası, string dosyayolu)
    {
       


        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dosyayolu);

        PdfContentByte waterMark;

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
            {
                int sayfa = reader.NumberOfPages;
                for (int i = 1; i <= sayfa; i++)
                {
                    waterMark = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);
                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(resimdosyası);
                    foreach (string file in files)
                    {
                        var resim = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C://Users//tufanc//source//repos//PdfStamp//PdfStamp//stampimage//" + Path.GetFileName(file));
                        
                       
                        resim.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 100);
                        waterMark.AddImage(resim);
                    }
                }
            }
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes(dosyayolu, bytes);



    }
```

Comment: Should'n you be incrementing these values in the loop? `resim.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 100);` They all have the same position.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void damga(string resimdosyası, string dosyayolu)
    {


        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dosyayolu);

        PdfContentByte waterMark;

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
            {

                int sayfa = reader.NumberOfPages;
                for (int i = 1; i <= sayfa; i++)
                {
                    waterMark = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);
                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(resimdosyası);
                    foreach (string file in files)
                    {
                        int imzasayisi = files.Length;
                        for (int imza = 1; imza <= imzasayisi; imza++)
                        {
                            

                        var resim = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C://Users//tufanc//source//repos//PdfStamp//PdfStamp//stampimage//" + Path.GetFileName(file)); 

                       
                            int imzax = 1;
                            int imzay = 100;

                            imzax = imzax * imza;
                            imzay = imzay * imza;

                            resim.SetAbsolutePosition(imzax, imzay);
                            
                            waterMark.AddImage(resim);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes(dosyayolu, bytes);



    }
```

I changed like this, but I set the for loop incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void damga(string resimdosyası, string dosyayolu)
    {


        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dosyayolu);

        PdfContentByte waterMark;

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {


            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
            {


                int sayfa = reader.NumberOfPages;
                for (int i = 1; i <= sayfa; i++)
                {
                    int imzax = 1;
                    int imzay = 1;


                    waterMark = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);
                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(resimdosyası);
                    int imzasayisi = files.Length;

                    foreach (string file in files)
                    {
                        var resim = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C://Users//tufanc//source//repos//PdfStamp//PdfStamp//stampimage//" + Path.GetFileName(file));

                        imzax = imzax + 100;
                        imzay = imzay + 1;

                        resim.SetAbsolutePosition(imzax, imzay);


                        waterMark.AddImage(resim);
                    }
                }

            }
            bytes = stream.ToArray();
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes(dosyayolu, bytes);



    }
```

this complete the work.